# How to select in a set of records having 0 or 1 value in a field, the record with value 1 only if exists, in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'wordstyped' containing 'idBook', 'guidUser', 'bookmarkLetter', 'letter',  'attemptWrong' and 'isCorrect'.

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong   isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         100             a       2              0
1       1         100             a       3              0
1       1         100             a       3              1
1       1         101             b       6              0
1       1         101             b       2              0
2       2         101             b       3              0
2       3         152             d       7              0
3       3         153             e       2              0
```

I want to select all the record with all their fields containing the max number of 'attemptWrong', but distinct triplets 'idBook', 'guidUser' and 'bookmarkLetter'. 
I've done this with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.bookmarkletter, w1.attemptsWrong
FROM wordstyped w1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook, 
MAX(attemptsWrong) AS maxAttemptsWrong 
FROM wordstyped 
GROUP BY bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook ) w2 
ON w1.bookmarkLetter = w2.bookmarkLetter AND w1.guidUser = w2.guidUser 
AND w1.guidUser = '1' 
AND w1.idBook ='1'
AND w1.attemptsWrong = w2.maxAttemptsWrong AND w1.bookmarkLetter >=0
AND w1.bookmarkLetter <=200 ORDER BY `w1`.`bookmarkletter` ASC
```

like in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/238794/2

Now, I want to select 'isCorrect' too, with value of 1 if at least one record ha value isCorrect=1 and 0 if all the records have value 0.

If I add w1.isCorrect to the first select statement in the example case 
like

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.bookmarkletter, w1.attemptsWrong, w1.isCorrect
FROM wordstyped w1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook, 
MAX(attemptsWrong) AS maxAttemptsWrong 
FROM wordstyped 
GROUP BY bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook ) w2 
ON w1.bookmarkLetter = w2.bookmarkLetter AND w1.guidUser = w2.guidUser 
AND w1.guidUser = '1' 
AND w1.idBook ='1'
AND w1.attemptsWrong = w2.maxAttemptsWrong AND w1.bookmarkLetter >=0
AND w1.bookmarkLetter <=200 ORDER BY `w1`.`bookmarkletter` ASC
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/238794/1), this set of records

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong   isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         101             b       6              0
1       1         101             b       2              0
2       2         101             b       3              0
```

return correctly

```
bookmarkLetter    attemptWrong    isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
101               6               0
```

while this set of records

```
idBook  guidUser  bookmarkLetter  letter  attemptWrong   isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         100             a       2              0
1       1         100             a       3              0
1       1         100             a       3              1
```

returns

```
bookmarkLetter    attemptWrong    isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
100               3               0
100               3               1
```

instead of

```
bookmarkLetter    attemptWrong    isCorrect
-------------------------------------------------------------------
100               3               1
```

How may I achieve the second result?

EDIT: The case in which I have isCorrect 1 happens always like in the example, i.e I have two record with attemptWrong that is the max value, one with isCorrect=0 and one with isCorrect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with aggregation and group by

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/238794/4

```
SELECT w1.bookmarkletter, max(w1.attemptsWrong), max(w1.isCorrect) 
  FROM wordstyped w1 INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook, MAX(attemptsWrong) AS maxAttemptsWrong 
    FROM wordstyped 
    GROUP BY bookmarkLetter, guidUser, idBook ) w2 
ON w1.bookmarkLetter = w2.bookmarkLetter AND w1.guidUser = w2.guidUser 
AND w1.guidUser = '1' 
AND w1.idBook ='1'
AND w1.attemptsWrong = w2.maxAttemptsWrong AND w1.bookmarkLetter >=0
AND w1.bookmarkLetter <=200 
group by w1.bookmarkletter
ORDER BY `w1`.`bookmarkletter` ASC
```

Comment: It feels simpler right now! :D Thank you very much, works perfectly. There is a specific reason why you got rid of the DISTINCT at the beginning?